# Calling matplotlib plot objects to show on Screen

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple question regarding matplotlib figure objects.

I have the following code in a function library named gauss that returns a figure:

```
def plot_3d(X,Y,Z):
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = Axes3D(fig1)
    surf = ax1.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    fig1.colorbar(surf,shrink=0.5,aspect=5)
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    ax1.set_zlabel('f(x,y)')
    return fig1
```

In the interpreter, I run the code with a given X,Y,Z

```
fig = gauss.plot_3d(X,Y,Z)
```

And the code calls the object. But once I close the object, how can I call it again?

Something along the lines of

```
plt.show(fig)
```

?

Comment: What is wrong with `plt.show(fig)`? That works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using Spyder with the interpreter inside and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that once you close a `Figure` instance through a GUI or otherwise, it's gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arg on `show` does not do what you think it does.  `show` eats `*args, **kwargs`, but it really just gets passed to a bool if it should block or not.

Once you have closed a figure it get deleted from `pyplot`'s registry of active figures.  If you still have a reference to the figure you *can* try to show it again by reaching into the internals of the figure and poking at the figure's canvas's manager's window.

ex (for the qt backend):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

then close the window, and then

```
fig.canvas.manager.window.show()
```

should make it pop back up.